# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'first'

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python and having trouble with this problem. I wrote this convert_link function while it returned the AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'first'. I don't understand where the tuple came from?

```
def convert_link(link):
    """Takes a linked list and returns a Python list with the same elements.

    >>> link = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
    >>> convert_link(link)
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    >>> convert_link(Link.empty)
    []
    """
    if link.first is Link.empty:
        return []
    return [link.first]+convert_link(link.rest)
```

this the class definition I was given:

```
class Link:
    """A linked list.

    >>> s = Link(1)
    >>> s.first
    1
    >>> s.rest is Link.empty
    True
    >>> s = Link(2, Link(3, Link(4)))
    >>> s.first = 5
    >>> s.rest.first = 6
    >>> s.rest.rest = Link.empty
    >>> s                                    # Displays the contents of repr(s)
    Link(5, Link(6))
    >>> s.rest = Link(7, Link(Link(8, Link(9))))
    >>> s
    Link(5, Link(7, Link(Link(8, Link(9)))))
    >>> print(s)                             # Prints str(s)
    <5 7 <8 9>>
    """
    empty = ()

    def __init__(self, first, rest=empty):
        assert rest is Link.empty or isinstance(rest, Link)
        self.first = first
        self.rest = rest

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.rest is not Link.empty:
            rest_repr = ', ' + repr(self.rest)
        else:
            rest_repr = ''
        return 'Link(' + repr(self.first) + rest_repr + ')'

    def __str__(self):
        string = '<'
        while self.rest is not Link.empty:
            string += str(self.first) + ' '
            self = self.rest
        return string + str(self.first) + '>'
```

This is what I got after running the code in terminal

```
File "/Users/yiting/Downloads/lab08/lab08.py", line 12, in convert_link
    return [link.first]+convert_link(link.rest)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/Users/yiting/Downloads/lab08/lab08.py", line 10, in convert_link
    if link.first is Link.empty:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'first'
```

Comment: Have you tried running your doctests? In particular `convert_link(Link.empty)`

Comment: Just tried , it says AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'first'.

Comment: Show us the full code that calls `convert_link()`.

Comment: Hello, I just updated the codes

Comment: `rest=empty` assigns an empty `tuple` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `convert_link` is called recursively, until it reaches the innermost instance of your `Link` class that in turn has a `link.rest` attribute of type `tuple`. This final `link.rest` (that contains a `tuple` instead of an instance of class `Link`) is then passed to `convert_link` that then tries to access the attribute `.first` that the `tuple` does not have.

A quick fix to your function would be to add at its beginning an `if` statement, that checks whether the `link` being used as input is an instance of the class `Link`, and if not converts it into a `Link` object:

```py
def convert_link(link):
    """Takes a linked list and returns a Python list with the same elements.

    >>> link = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
    >>> convert_link(link)
    [1, 2, 3, 4] 
    >>> convert_link(Link.empty)
    []
    """
    if not isinstance(link, Link):
        link = Link(link)
    if link.first == Link.empty:
        return []
    return [link.first] + convert_link(link.rest)


link = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
print(convert_link(link))
# Prints:
#
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Another solution would be to add an additional condition to your `if link. First == Link.empty`, checking whether `link` has an attribute named `first`:

```py
def convert_link(link):
    """Takes a linked list and returns a Python list with the same elements.

    >>> link = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
    >>> convert_link(link) [1, 2, 3, 4] 
    >>> convert_link(Link.empty) []
    """
    # The order of both conditions matters here
    if not hasattr(link, 'first') or link.first == Link.empty:
        return []
    return [link.first] + convert_link(link.rest)


link = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
print(convert_link(link))
# Prints:
#
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

A third solution would be to change the `if` statement like so:

```py
def convert_link(link):
    """Takes a linked list and returns a Python list with the same elements.

    >>> link = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
    >>> convert_link(link) [1, 2, 3, 4] 
    >>> convert_link(Link.empty) []
    """
    if link == Link.empty:
        return []
    return [link.first] + convert_link(link.rest)


link = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
print(convert_link(link))
# Prints:
#
# [1, 2, 3, 4]

print(convert_link(Link.empty))
# Prints:
#
# []
```

### Note

Adding a `print` statement right before the second return from your original `convert_link` might help better understanding what's going on inside the `convert_link` function. If you add `print(link.rest, type(link.rest))`, you would see the following messages being printed to your console:

```py
def convert_link(link):
    """Takes a linked list and returns a Python list with the same elements.

    >>> link = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
    >>> convert_link(link) [1, 2, 3, 4] 
    >>> convert_link(Link.empty) []
    """
    # The order of both conditions matters here
    if not hasattr(link, 'first') or link.first == Link.empty:
        return []
    print(link.rest, type(link.rest))
    return [link.first] + convert_link(link.rest)


link = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
print(convert_link(link))
"""
<2 3 4> <class '__main__.Link'>
<3 4> <class '__main__.Link'>
<4> <class '__main__.Link'>
() <class 'tuple'>      # <---- Here's the problem
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-222-5fde863fdd94> in <module>
     14 
     15 
---> 16 convert_link(link)

4 frames
<ipython-input-222-5fde863fdd94> in convert_link(link)
      8 
      9     # The order of both conditions matters here
---> 10     if link.first == Link.empty:
     11         return []
     12     print(link.rest, type(link.rest))

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'first'
"""
```

You could also observe the problem using a more direct approach:

```py
print(type(link.rest))
print(type(link.rest.rest))
print(type(link.rest.rest.rest))
print(type(link.rest.rest.rest.rest))
# Prints:
#
# <class '__main__.Link'>
# <class '__main__.Link'>
# <class '__main__.Link'>
# <class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Thank you, Erik. Your answer is thorough and I appreciate the different methods you have shown. They are very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You test `if link.first is Link.empty:`. But `Link.empty` is only *ever* the value for `link.rest` (to indicate end of linked list).

You meant to just test `if link is Link.empty:`, because when you reached the end of the linked list, you'd recurse calling with `Link.empty` itself, not something that has a `first` attribute of `Link.empty`.

Your function is correct, after that one tweak:

```
def convert_link(link):
    """Takes a linked list and returns a Python list with the same elements.

    >>> link = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
    >>> convert_link(link)
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    >>> convert_link(Link.empty)
    []
    """
    if link is Link.empty:  # Removed .first
        return []
    return [link.first]+convert_link(link.rest)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now the code runs properly.

Comment: @Yiting: If your problem is completely solved by an answer, you can click the green check mark on the left side of the answer to indicate your problem is solved (and you can and should up-vote any answers that were helpful to you, even if they're not complete or as helpful as others).

Comment: Got it! thank you! Since I don't seem to have enough reputation to cast a vote now as a new beginner, I will keep working on StackOverflow to raise and maybe eventually solve more questions and gain reputation.

Answer (score -3):

There is no `first` or `first()` attr in tuple. You need to use indexing like `mytuple[0]`.

Comment: That's not applicable to this question. The tuple is an empty-tuple sentinel.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but does nothing to explain the actual problem.